# PyGears Error: No system libbz2 headers could be found. Make sure your system has a libz installed

Tags: python, linux, pygears

I got error `No system libbz2 headers could be found.  Make sure your system has a libz installed` while installing PyGears. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu on WSL, please try this one.

```
sudo apt install libbz2-dev
```

The name of the package could vary depending on Linux distribution, but more or less that's it.